# How come the output of this C program is 1?

Tags: c, for-loop, casting, output, unsigned-char

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char c = (int) 0.54;
    for(; c++; printf("%d", c));

    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I run the program the output is displayed as `1`

How can the output be 1? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `for` loop's 3rd expression never executes because its 2nd expression evaluates to false because `c` is initialized to 0. Because the 2nd expression executes, `c` becomes 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line- `unsigned char c=(int)0.54;` char actually stores the ASCII code of the character so in another way it's an integer which stores the data in this way :
The compiler converts the number stored into the character from decimal number system to binary number system and  takes into consideration only the first 8 bits from the right of that number represented in binary.(we don't need to consider the case of negative numbers since you use an unsigned char)-so as a result the variable `c` takes 0 as value at the end of this line.

For the second line of your code- `for(;c++;printf("%d",c));` :
so we have a for loop
( for (INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; AFTERTHOUGHT))

** In the INITIALIZATION part , Leaving this empty is fine, it's just equivalent that you have already initialized the variable that you are going to use as loop variable .

** In  the CONDITION part , c++  is equivalent to c++!=0. It keeps the for loop running until c++==0.(in your case c is initialized by 0 , so  we will have c++=0 and the program immediately exits the for loop).

** In  the AFTERTHOUGHT part , The printf  is run at the end of each iteration but doesn't change the value of c.(since the condition c++!=0 is not verified the code will not write the iteration, so it will not pass to printf)

`printf("%d",c);` will display 1 ( c++ in your loop  is used as condition and in the same time to increment variable c by 1 ; c++  post-increment operator uses the principle 'use-then-change' so , c is incremented by 1 exactly after exiting the for loop , and c becomes equal to 1).

Comment: That first paragraph is wrong. There are no ASCII values involved. Variable `c` stores the value 0 because the numerical value `0` is assigned to it, not the ASCII value of any character.

Comment: Yes ,  but i'm trying to explain what char can store in general (it always stores an integer value)